# Como sumar horas a una fecha en mysql.?

Tags: mysql

Hola tengo una tabla donde quiero sumar horas al campo de fecha dependiendo del día por ejemplo de lunes a jueves sumar 24 horas pero si es viernes sumar 72 horas si es sábado 48 horas y su es domingo 24 horas, alguien sabe si es posible..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo validando el día de la semana de tu fecha con `DAYOFWEEK` solo tienes que considerar que MySQL toma como primer día de la semana el domingo (1=domingo,2=lunes,...). Extrayendo dicho día, con con la sentencia `DATE_ADD`, puedes agregar las horas.

Básicamente tu consulta quedaría:

```
SELECT 
    IF(
      DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 6, -- viernes
      DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL 72 HOUR),
      IF(
        DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 7, -- sabado
        DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL 48 HOUR),
        DATE_ADD(fecha, INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
      )
    )
```

donde se valida que tu fecha = 6 (viernes) suma las 72 horas y fecha = 7 (sabado) suma las 48 horas, y los demás días 24 horas

Comment: Me servio, gracias